# How to generate a number of random vectors starting from a given one

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of values and would like to create a matrix from that, where each row is my starting point vector multiplied by a sample from a (normal) distribution.
The number of rows of this matrix will then vary in dependence from the number of samples I want.

```
%pylab
my_vec = array([1,2,3])
my_rand_vec = my_vec*randn(100)
```

Last command does not work, because array shapes do not match.
I could think of using a `for` loop, but I am trying to leverage on array operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
my_rand_vec = my_vec[None,:]*randn(100)[:,None]
```

For small numbers I get for example

```
import numpy as np
my_vec = np.array([1,2,3])
my_rand_vec = my_vec[None,:]*np.random.randn(5)[:,None]
my_rand_vec

# array([[ 0.45422416,  0.90844831,  1.36267247],
#        [-0.80639766, -1.61279531, -2.41919297],
#        [ 0.34203295,  0.6840659 ,  1.02609885],
#        [-0.55246431, -1.10492863, -1.65739294],
#        [-0.83023829, -1.66047658, -2.49071486]])
```

Your solution `my_vec*rand(100)` does not work because `*` corresponds to the element-wise multiplication which only works if both arrays have identical shapes.

What you have to do is adding an additional dimension using `[None,:]` and `[:,None]` such that numpy's [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) works.

As a side note I would recommend not to use `pylab`. Instead, use `import as` in order to include modules as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5748895/4367286).

Answer (score 2):

It is the outer product of vectors:

```
my_rand_vec = numpy.outer(randn(100), my_vec)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the dimensions of the array you require to `numpy.random.randn`:

```
my_rand_vec = my_vec*np.random.randn(100,3)
```

To multiply each vector by the *same* random number, you need to add an extra axis:

```
my_rand_vec = my_vec*np.random.randn(100)[:,np.newaxis]
```